# How can I compare two data properties in Protege?

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I am trying to build a pc configurator using protege, and I am trying to compare the socket type of the CPU with the Motherboard. 
I have a CPU class with data property socket type and so does the motherboard. As for the moment, however, I am failing to compare both as the PC assembled should have a CPU and Motherboard with the same socket type. Does anyone know if or how this is possible?

edit 1: Yes, I have a class hierarchy with PC component as parent and cpu, motherboard and others as childs. With compare I mean that when assembling a PC with the components I have defined, given a motherboard, it would have to pick a CPU that has the same socket type property as the motherboard (if motherboard has base AM4 the CPU socket should be == AM4). I dont really have a prefered way to model, I am very new to protege but I am currently trying to learn and was stuck in this problem.

Comment: are those CPU and Motherboard entities really classes? And what means compare? MY what? SPARQL query? Anyways, would be way easier when you use individuals, but I guess this depends on your preferred modeling way

Comment: thanks for your feedback, I tried to address it with my edit:)

Comment: I still don't understand what you're doing, Protege is an ontology editor, but where do you do you PC configuration and where and how do you want to compare PC parts. I mean, where is the application logic? Remember, Protege is just the editor for your ontology, anything beyond needs to write code, either as standalone application or as Protege plugin. I mean, you have to write the logic behind the recommendation of parts given the already declared parts in your PC config.

Comment: I see, In my head, I wanted for a hypothetical costumer to just specify the purpose of the PC without having to think about the specs. So he would specify the use case and protege would deliver the assembled PC using relationships in protege where I define what is "good" for each use case and then the relationships would take care of the compatibility between components. I guess that is not possible then? Or can I use SPARKL in the background to produce this queries? I just wanted for it to be invisible for the customer

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) along with the desired inference that you want to obtain?